# Print multilevel array in typescript according to a format

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to print the below variable according to the mentioned format. Could someone please help?

**Data**

```
export const shop_items: Inventory:{
    Toys{
        Balls: {
            BallId: 001uy,
            BallName: Soccerball,
            SignedBy: David_Beckham,
        },
    },
    Books:{
        Novel: {
            BookId: ‘001fd’,
            BookName: ‘Beauty and the beast’,  
        },
        Puzzle: {
            BookId: ‘002sz’,
            BookName: ‘Sherlock Holmes’,  
        },
        Sci-fi: {
            BookId: ’003tr’,
            BookName: ‘Dr.Gadget’,  
        },
    }
}
```

**Format**

The variables under the toys are just printing as it is. But the Data under the Books should come as a path

```
BallId : 001uy
BallName : Soccerball
SignedBy : David_Beckham

/Books/Novel/BookId : 001fd
/Books/Puzzle/BookId : 002sz
/Books/Sci-fi/BookId : 003tr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves your problem. Try it on the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=40&ssc=92&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgGwVAvFA3rRCCSATALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbiyQDk4BbCI0y2hgZQppUIeGCAD8nctRpQAvnQBQoSLAD2qgNaoMazfknd6ujS3YHpfAUJHio52rIVLw0HFQBuEKsFVkQ2zBh1DWIiTABtHGAIVnsaAF0iY1k5KAAyHQAVVRBQnUjo2JIpWkSoRmQU%20QUAY1UqUhIAC1UwAH0KQry3T29ffzR0BXLs3LDh8oq8ocnJ%20CR9KAAiAAYVgEYAVxAlgBoJ2fmEUw5l3lUamogyACNsPYPJ-kFhUSIlgBE4dwo8NpgIDUNE02A9ZrJ9uUIRMgpppo8mKpPAhxrNyrCNItVhsAGZ4MFojEnd4AuCbUBQOBUPBQYBNaA3CBwUgEqGQyYABU2AC9uQhTjNCcEsWsAEzEbmsubBYlnelkBAXLQACVUCHYxCl0NmS14NQoAFocRQlqihXpCMs1gBmchS9EytinT5kAB0AHE4HgaBBgFr2dDqgocZsqDVgBR6lAwNxgBiABRUJ1xXZQG7BIgYgCUgvKdQaaogrsVNHjAAMMQB6AAk6CT7FklfTFqItebGldGPwsjLWcUjmDofDkao0djR3jaewmewOce%20eIheLqlLFewizb2E767wPb78-qi-5y9XR1lm6Q2%20YTr3ilmC6XJfL-Fo1jeUAvCFdzzfIFvTkcAB5G4ACtAWAV0vCkCBiHjYgWnaToYmIV1RmILNXRxXwAFE4BqJp43jdxECIcIuGkVMjniLNUAAPjHag42wIjEHCdZ4igLMswUYCwPDSDvEoGC4IQjouk7YJ0MwnC8IIliUSgMiShoSjgmouiGO8BNiIQcIVniXYdLYjiuKAA).

```
type Ball = { BallId: string; BallName: string; SignedBy?: string };
type Book = { BookId: string; BookName: string; SignedBy? : string}

type Inventory = { Books: { [Item: string]:  Book} } & { Toys: { [Item: string]:  Ball } };
const shop_items: Inventory = {
  Toys: {
    Balls: {
      BallId: "001uy",
      BallName: "Soccerball",
      SignedBy: "David_Beckham",
    },
  },
  Books: {
    Novel: {
      BookId: "001fd",
      BookName: "Beauty and the beast",
    },
    Puzzle: {
      BookId: "002sz",
      BookName: "Sherlock Holmes",
    },
    "Sci-fi": {
      BookId: "003tr",
      BookName: "Dr.Gadget",
    },
  },
};

function printBook(name: string, book: Book){
    console.log(`Book/${name}/bookId: ${book.BookId}`);
}

function printBall( ball: Ball){
    console.log(`BallId: ${ball.BallId}`);
    console.log(`BallName: ${ball.BallName}`);
    console.log(`SingnedBy: ${ball.SignedBy}`);

}
Object.entries(shop_items.Toys).forEach((val: [string, Ball]) => printBall(val[1] ))
Object.entries(shop_items.Books).forEach((val: [string, Book]) => printBook(val[0],val[1] )
```

Comment: This works pretty well. Thank you @heaxyh